# HTML/Javascript How to make "translator"

Tags: javascript, html

How would I make a translator that translates some text that has been inputted by the user?

After they inputted their text that they want to be translated it would be stored in a variable. Then on a text file (`english.txt`), it would find the English version of what they had inputted.

```
1. Hello
2. There
```

It would then tell the program what line the English word is on and then open another text file (`language.txt`) with the translations.

```
1. Test
2. Pending
```

Using that line then it would replace the word with the corresponding line

So, for example, the input is `Hello There` then it would be translated to `Test Pending`
How would I go about doing this in HTML/Javascript?

** The files would be somewhere to 50,000 lines

Comment: Please show examples of your code so we can see what you already tried and so we know where you are stuck

Comment: I have no idea on how I would do this. I've looked up to see if anybody has done this before and can't seem to find any sources. If people have done it please tell me.

Comment: `txt` files? That sounds like a job for a database.

Comment: @Handge what you are asking is way too broad and not what SO is for. A question on SO needs to be a problem you have encountered when trying to code this yourself. Generally it is expected that you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your existing code so we can replicate the issue. Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Do you have a source that could help me on this then?

Comment: @Handge no this is beyond my skill level but I would suggest looking into mySQL databases to store your 50,000 lines of text and then PHP to retrieve the data.

HTML, CSS and JS are usually only used for the front end of a site/ web app and I doubt they are sufficent to do something like this even if that was desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a very open question and as a result, there are a million ways of tackling this problem. However, I'd say that generally, you'd want to store these translations in a database and query them through a Web Api.

You should also realise, that a word by word translation will not give you very good translations, since you're not taking context or synonyms into account.

*For example: "bat" could refer to an animal, a wooden implement with a handle and a solid surface, or the action of batting away something.*

---

But if you do want to implement this and want to use as little different technologies as possible (and rely on static files), then you **could** do something as follows...
Convert your two input files to a single [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) file, with a format like:

```
{
    "Hello": "Test",
    "There": "Pending",
}
```

When the user enters a translation, split the input text by space using [string.split(" ")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), which will return an array of keys.
Next step is to find the keys inside your json using `json[key];`